# Call function from string inside object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, object

I have a function name in a string:

```
 var func = "doTest";
```

I need this function to be applied to the current instance ("this");

So I need it to call:

```
 this.doTest();
```

How can I do this? I cannot go via window.

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use the construct of `object[functionName]();`, like so:

```
function Person() {};
Person.prototype.speak = function() { alert('ohai'); };
var john = new Person, action = 'speak';

john[action]();
```

Alternative style:

```
var Person = {  
  speak: function() { alert('ohai'); }, 
  speakDelegate: function() { var action = 'speak'; this[action](); } 
};
Person.speakDelegate();
```

Comment: I updated my answer. If that still isn't sufficient, please give us more details. What does `this` resolve to? Are you dealing with a jQuery object? moreinfo.

Answer (score 6):

```
this[func]();
```

No need to `.call` or `.apply` since context is held in the reference.

For example:

```
var obj = {
   doTest: function(){ console.log(this); },
   fn: function(){ var name='doTest'; this[name](); }
};
obj.fn(); // logs the object, proving this has the correct context.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
var funcObj = this["doTest"];
funcObj.apply(this);
```

What this does is grab the member named `doTest` from `this`.  It then executes the function via `apply` and tells javascript to bind `this` as `this` within the function.  I think the example is a bit less confusing if you consider the same code on a non-this value

```
var obj = {
  doTest: function() {
    console.log("doTest called");
  }
};

var doTestFunc = obj["doTest"];
doTestFunc.apply(obj);
```

In this case the method `doTest` will be executed with the value `obj` as `this`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can just do:

```
$(this)[func]()
```